# Where is the Numerical Digitizing Plugin?

Tags: qgis

I know this question has occurred before, and quires have been speculated about its existence. However, the only questions I can find about it are all regarding out dated QGIS versions. Does the **Numerical Digitizing plugin** exist on QGIS v3.2?

Comment: Don't think it does at the moment but there is the **Lat Lon Tools** plugin which could be an alternative.

Comment: Thankyou, also would the **lat long tools plugin** allow me to add a point just by entering its known Eastings and Northings?

Comment: Yes, there are five icons in the **Lat Lon Tools** toolbar. If you edit your point layer and select _Lat Lon Digitize_, you will be able to add the coordinates of your feature and specify the CRS etc.

Comment: perfect, it works a treat

Comment: Great, will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently is has not been ported over to QGIS 3 but an alternative would be to use the **Lat Lon Tools** plugin.

This also allows you to add point features by entering the coordinates and specifying the CRS.